# How to get the dryad easy

Tags: terraria-console

While I was playing a blood moon it was 12 am and before I could defeat the eoc he fled I just want the dryad. Plz help.

EDIT:been trying it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You have to defeat the Eye of Cthulhu, the Eater of Worlds, the Brain of Cthulhu or Skeletron to have the dryad spawning in your world (and an empty house).

The Eye of Cthulhu is the easiest boss, you should keep trying beating him.

(Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they solve your problem)

Comment: Thnx man he was easy by why did I do 12 am.

Comment: Plus I made a special room in my hotel for her.